# Continuous functions exercise in Spivak's Calculus

Tags: calculus, limits

This is exercise $9$   in chapter $6$ (on continuous functions) of *Calculus* by Michael Spivak.

> (a) Suppose $f$ is *not* continuous at $a$. Prove that for some number $\epsilon>0$ there are numbers $x$ arbitrarily close to $a$ with $|f(x) - f(a)|>\epsilon$. Illustrate graphically.
>
> (b) Conclude that for some number $\epsilon>0$ *either* there are numbers $x$ arbitrarily close to $a$ with $f(x)<f(a) - \epsilon$ *or* there are numbers $x$ arbitrarily close to $a$  with $f(x)>f(a) + \epsilon$.

I am having difficulty with $b)$. Consider $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as follows

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0  & x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} \\
\frac 12 & x=1\\
1 & \{x \in \mathbb{Q} \ | x \neq 1\}\\ 
\end{cases}$

Note $f$ is not continuous at $x=1$. We will thus take $a=1$.

I am having difficulty finding the appropriate $\epsilon$ which satisfies the "either/or" requirement. If we take $\epsilon\geq\frac 12$ then $f$ satisfies neither of the two requirements, whereas if we take $0<\epsilon < \frac 12$ it satisfies both. What mistake am I making?

Comment: Your mistake is only in the interpretation of Spivak's sentence. He never said he used `xor`, to speak computer scientists' jargon.

Comment: Yes: the meaning here is  "at least one of the two must hold," *not* "exactly one of the two must hold."

Comment: Doesn't "either" imply exclusivity?

Comment: I was always taught that "either/or" meant xor in my undergraduate...

Comment: See [this discussion](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13889/does-either-a-or-b-preclude-both-a-and-b) on English.SE. In short: "Either" should imply exclusivity, but in many mathematical statements the authors do not follow this rule.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that there are two different Davids who have responded to this thread.

Comment: @David: Who's the culprit? :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "either/or" does not exclude the possibility of both being true here. It is being used to emphasize that  what is meant is not
$$\exists \varepsilon > 0 \ \forall \delta > 0 \ \exists x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta) \quad [f(x) > f(a) + \varepsilon \ \text{ or } \ f(x) < f(a) -\varepsilon]$$
as in the first part, but rather
$$\exists \varepsilon > 0 \ [\forall \delta > 0 \ \exists x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta) \ \ f(x) > f(a) + \varepsilon \quad \text{ or } \quad \forall \delta > 0 \ \exists x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta) \ \  f(x) < f(a) - \varepsilon].$$

It is really being used as a way of stressing that the quantifiers and connectives are placed differently, with the "or" occurring at a higher level in the structure of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

> there are numbers $x$ arbitrarily close to $a$ with $f(x)<f(a) -
> > \epsilon$ *or* there are numbers $x$ arbitrarily close to $a$  with
>   $f(x)>f(a) + \epsilon$.

allows both possibilities to occur (the use of the words "*either*" and "*or*" does not imply that the alternatives are mutually exclusive).

Comment: This is evidently a reading comprehension thing, but when we say "or" doesn't that mean mutually exclusive? "Either Joe will go to the movies, or he will watch football". Is it not implicit that he won't do both? (sorry English is my second language)

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 In math, "or" means "and/or".

Comment: @littleO Okay, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 This may be more suited to English.SE (where [such a question was already asked](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13889/does-either-a-or-b-preclude-both-a-and-b)), but essentially, it depends quite a bit on context.